# Why Can't I Get Google Adwords API To Work on Amazon EC2 Instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, google-ads-api

I'm having another Amazon EC2 issue, it seems. For this application I'm developing I need to use Google Adwords API to retrieve some domain data, but it isn't working on our Amazon EC2 Instance. If I put it on our BlueHost server, it works fine. However, it does not work on Amazon EC2. If I try running Google Adwords, it just shows a blank screen and doesn't show any errors.

I have installed SOAP on my Amazon EC2 instance. Before I installed SOAP, it returned an error saying that SOAP was not installed. Now it just shows nothing, even though if I comment out the call to the function that extracts data from Adwords API.

I even added:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
```

To my index page in order to ensure that it will display errors. Still nothing.

This is the AMI I'm using:

```
AMI-6AE81503
```

I'm sure that there's some configuration which is preventing it from working right, but I'm not sure what. For a while I was wondering if SOAP used some special port or protocol which I've got disabled, but it seems to just use port 80, which is enabled. So I'm not sure what could be causing the issue.

Again, I have installed SOAP, and both Apache and PHP are using the latest version.

Thanks in advanced...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after spending most of the day configuring a new instance on Amazon EC2 (this time with an Ubuntu server), I finally got it working. It was just that AMI that was giving me trouble, it seems...